# how to ignore node and specify which nodes to be added to queue

Tags: c, queue, nodes

i want a node created only when name!=admin is entered .
if admin is entered i will go to admin menu so i can change and the global variables ,then  when i leave i want to continue and get a name !=admin that will be the begining of the new node created .
if u need more details please tell me .its my using stack overflow so sorry for the bad explanations.

```
int incnode(TNOD *p) {
    char text[30];
    char currency[15];
    float amount;
    int adminExit=0;
    do{
        printf("Enter your name: \n");
        fflush(stdin);

        // Use fgets to read user input safely
        fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);

        // Remove the trailing newline character
        text[strcspn(text, "\n")] = '\0';


        if (strcmp(text, "admin") == 0) {
           adminExit=admin_menu();

        }else{
            p->string = (char *)malloc(strlen(text) + 1); // +1 for the null terminator
        strcpy(p->string, text);

        printf("Enter the currency to buy: ");
        scanf("%s", currency);

        printf("Enter the amount to buy: ");
        scanf("%f", &amount);

        p->amount = amount;
        p->currency = (char *)malloc(strlen(currency) + 1);
        strcpy(p->currency, currency);
        }
        if (strcmp(currency, "dollar") == 0) {
        buy_DOLLAR(amount);
    } else if (strcmp(currency, "lbp") == 0) {
         buy_LBP(amount);
    } else if (strcmp(currency, "pound") == 0) {
        buy_POUND(amount);
    } else if (strcmp(currency, "euro") == 0) {
        buy_EURO(amount);
    }
        return 1;}
        while(!adminExit);

return 0;

}
```

i tried a lot of stuff ,and i think that i need a  flag after admin_menu that states its not a new node ,and another after the else that states to create a new node.

edit: so if for a example i have a queue where each node has text(a name) if the input text is admin i dont want this specific node to be added to queue ,i want to just call the admin_menu function so i can change variables ,and after that to just restart and take a new name ,then if name is different then admin a new node is created .
in other words i want a way to acces admin menu during the part where i take input name .
thanks for the feedback !
edit 2:
i fixed it lol

```
int incnode(TNOD *p) {
    char text[30];
    char currency[15];
    float amount;
    int adminExit=0;

        printf("Enter your name: \n");
        fflush(stdin);

        // Use fgets to read user input safely
        fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);

        // Remove the trailing newline character
        text[strcspn(text, "\n")] = '\0';


        while (strcmp(text, "admin") == 0) {
        admin_menu();
        printf("Enter a new name: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
        text[strcspn(text, "\n")] = '\0';
        }


        p->string = (char *)malloc(strlen(text) + 1); // +1 for the null terminator
        strcpy(p->string, text);

        printf("Enter the currency to buy: ");
        scanf("%s", currency);

        printf("Enter the amount to buy: ");
        scanf("%f", &amount);

        p->amount = amount;
        p->currency = (char *)malloc(strlen(currency) + 1);
        strcpy(p->currency, currency);

        if (strcmp(currency, "dollar") == 0) {
        buy_DOLLAR(amount);
    } else if (strcmp(currency, "lbp") == 0) {
         buy_LBP(amount);
    } else if (strcmp(currency, "pound") == 0) {
        buy_POUND(amount);
    } else if (strcmp(currency, "euro") == 0) {
        buy_EURO(amount);
    }
        return 1;}
```

this is the new fixed code that does what i want ,if anyone wants to know what exaclty i wanted feel free to ask.

Comment: I do not get what you are asking. I see two possible questions "How to not insert a node?" and "How to detect the admin name?". The first is extremely easy, the second reasonably easy (assuming you know to use the suitable function for string comparing). You seem however to have a problem with the combination of the two. Please elaborate. The shown code seems too complex an [mre] to discuss either question, or even the combination. Please try to tailor to the problem.

Comment: Setting `adminExit` to true doesn't skip the code following the if-else. It continues executing until it sees the `while(!adminExit)` It doesn't jump there immediately.

Comment: @ALI-LKS Too many global variables that make the code unreadable.